# Event handler for close buttom on wordpress gallery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have gallery on wordpress site http://thevastcreative.com/bluebird/update_theme/farm-school/
I need add event handler to close button.
I need close gallery window, when i click on this button.
I use jquery function 
but it doesn't work.
Please tell me how correct write event handler for it.

Thanks

Comment: `I use jquery function but it doesn't work` post your attempt in question

Comment: Indeed you have to fix errors prior to expect anything else to work as expected...

Comment: Here is it
 <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
function myclose(){
   $("#mybutton").click(function(){$("#image_gallery").dialog("close");});
}
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You are facing scope issue, just don't wrap function inside ready handler callback, which is creating private scope:

*{and btw, no need to rebind a new click event on same element, in your code, you are calling myclose function from inline onclick attribute}*

```
function myclose() {
    $("#image_gallery").dialog("close");
}
```

Comment: I was rewrite now on it

Comment: <button id="mybutton" onClick="myclose();"><img src="" alt="" 
          style="vertical-align: middle" >Close</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myclose() {
    $("#DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer").dialog("close");
}
</script>

but it doesn't work too